# overide third party module service class magento2

Tags: php, magento2.4.2

i'am using third party extension and i want to overide its service class resides in
vendor/modulename/Services/ClassName into my custom module, iam  trying to overide it with prefrence in di xml.

> preference for="Vendor\Modulename\Services\ProductsData"
> type="Custom\Modulename\Services\ProductsData" />

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Modulename\Services;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;

class ProductsData extends \Vendor\Modulename\Services\ProductsData
{

protected $_categoryFactory;

public function __construct(
        CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($categoryFactory);
    }

public function getCategory($categoryid)
    {
        $_category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryid); //error coming on this line, not able to get the class.
        return $_category;
    }

}
```

its giving me an error:

> call to a member function load on null in Custom\Modulename\Services\ProductsData

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined construct function properly please check.

```
    public function __construct(
        CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
    ) {
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        parent::__construct($categoryFactory);
    }
```